# Ubuntu 18.4 can't install latest version of speedtest-cli

Tags: command-line, 18.04

I've installed `speedtest-cli 2.0.0` and then I removed it using this commands:

```
apt-get remove speedtest-cli
```

And then tried to install the latest version `2.1.2` but when I run `pip3 install speedtest-cli` this message prompts up:

```
Requirement already satisfied: speedtest-cli in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
```

I then tried to run `apt-get remove --auto-remove speedtest-cli` but that message is still there.

How can `speedtest-cli` be properly removed and then installed again (version `2.1.2` this time)?

**UPDATE:** I ran `pip3 uninstall speedtest-cli` and then it worked to run `pip3 install speedtest-cli` but when i run `speedtest-cli` i get this message:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/speedtest-cli: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is in `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages`? Is `speedtest` there? If you perform `locate speedtest` does it have any location?

Comment: @DankyNanky i don't know what `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages` is. When i run `locate speedtest` i don't get any message at all. :(

Comment: `pip3 uninstall speedtest-cli` again, then `sudo pip3 install speedtest-cli` to install it as root. It works fine for me. If it doesnt for you, edit your answer with the results of `sudo updatedb && locate speedtest` and (optionnaly `ls /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages | grep speedtest`, but locate will give that resutat as well) as DankyNanky asked

Comment: @B.duGaray it works! After i ran the first three commands (and now i finally get some more accurate results from speedtest) Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install it as root and so, will be installed in your PATH. So uninstall what you have installed

`pip3 uninstall speedtest-cli`

Then install it again, but as root

`sudo pip3 install speedtest-cli`

You can now run `speedtest-cli` (or shorter : `speedtest` as you told me) in your terminal (no root needed)

Comment: Add this one too: `sudo updatedb && locate speedtest` (from your answer) i think it helped. Also for `speedtest-cli-2.1.2` you have to run `speedtest` only - without `-cli`

Comment: I found that `speedtest` and `speedtest-cli` are the same command (try it yourself with the `--version` flag but you're right, yours shorter. Also, `sudo updatedb && locate speedtest` didn't help since it would help us to help you, determining where the `speedtest-cli` packages were (and that's all)

Comment: oh, oky :D - but the `updatedb` thingie helped because before that running `locate speedtest` prompted nothing

Comment: `updatedb` update your "file index" the `locate` command use. If the files on your system are recents, especially since the last reboot, locate won't find them